# How fast can iPhone to be programmed take 2 pictures at one time?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avfoundation, photo

I wish to write an iphone app that allows your to take 2 consecutive pictures in a very short time, and I wonder if it is achievable. May apps in the market seems to only take low resolution still frames out of video stream, so I wonder if fast capturing full resolution photo is feasible.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what your timing and photo resolution requirements are.
The time to take pictures depends on the hardware and the desired resolution.

Use the API in AVFoundation to take pictures asynchronously. In particular the method `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847140/550177) for details

I've measured the minimum time between 2 photos on an iPhone 4S with different configurations:

- `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium`, back camera: **about 0.043s**
- `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, back camera (8MP): **about 0.3s**
- `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, front camera (640x480): **about 0.027s**