# Swift Dictionary is nil when adding output settings

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, avcapturesession, ios-camera

When accessing the camera and trying to capture a still, I get an error adding the output settings. It says that I can't add a nil to AVCaptureOutput

Here's the code:

```
var imageCaptured : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

let outputSettings:Dictionary = [AVVideoCodecJPEG:AVVideoCodecKey]
imageCaptured?.outputSettings = outputSettings
captureSession.addOutput(imageCaptured) //error here
```

This is the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** **Can't add a nil AVCaptureOutput'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting `imageCaptured` to anything. It's nil.

For example how to initialize it, see [How To Use AVCaptureStillImageOutput To Take Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296827/how-to-use-avcapturestillimageoutput-to-take-picture).

Comment: I'm not setting it to the Codecs in the Dictionary? Your link is Objective-C... My code above is what I've tried to convert from Obj-C to Swift

Comment: Correct, you are not setting it, or it would not be nil. You have declared it to be a var of type AVCaptureStillImageOutput? but have not assigned anything to it.

Comment: Doh! I was missing imageCaptured = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()