# ios7 UIImagePickerController issues only takes photo once and camera is not ready

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, camera

I have been suffering from the common issues discussed at length in this post:

[UIImagePickerController error: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890003/uiimagepickercontroller-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-re)

```
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
```

I *have tried the various workarounds* discussed in that thread but to no avail. The issues I have now are:

- If I clean and build the app then the first time that the camera is utilised it allows me to take a photo
- Every attempt to take a photo thereafter fails:

  - If I try to take another photo the camera freezes
  - If I close the app and reopen it and try to take another photo, pressing the capture button does not do anything
- Using custom controls (i.e. completely customizing camera capture behaviour) gives rise to a warning in the console **camera is not ready**.

  ```
  [picker takePhoto];
  ```

I am testing on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1 installed, XCode 5 with version 7.1 of the SDK.

This occurs when running the app and when installed the app via an archived build.

Interestingly the most recent post on the above-mentioned thread suggests that similar problems occur with Apple's own Photobucket example ([UIImagePickerController error: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890003/uiimagepickercontroller-error-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-re?answertab=votes#comment34750347_19743276))

Any other suggestions would be welcome. A solution built using AVFoundation may be viable if the effort is warranted, i.e. if the above-mentioned issues are specifically `UIImagePickerController` -related and not because my hardware is crap or I've overlooked something.

Comment: What does this question have anything to do with the Xcode IDE? The `xcode` tag should only be used for questions related to the IDE itself.

Comment: Thanks Leo I'm tag-dyslexic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate I didn't give any concrete examples here - it was a case of *I have exhausted the UIImagePickerController workarounds give me some inspiration* and hair-pulling.

Creating a still-photo capture feature using AVFoundation proved more flexible, less resource-intensive and seems to be less problematic than the out-of-the-box UIImagePickerController.

This thread is useful if you decide to go down that route:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667775/1526144